# How to ensure I don't keep entering data to my room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am teaching myself how to use flow and I am using fakeData to try and insert some data in the room database, I however noticed my init block inserts new data everytime I launch the application. I was wondering how can I ensure I don't insert all the time.

```
class StudentRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val studentDao: StudentDao
) : StudentRepository {

    override suspend fun getStudents(): Flow<List<StudentData>> {
        return studentDao.loadAllStudentsLists()
    }

    init{
        GlobalScope.launch {
            provideStudentData().forEach{ students -> studentDao.insertAllStudents(students)}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `@Insert()` in your dao?

If yes, you may use `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)` as it will replace the existing data with the same `PrimaryKey` in your table.

If you don't want to keep insert value in your db, why not move away `insertAllStudents()` from `init()` block? Based on lifecycle, when the application is launched, `init()` will be trigger first before `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

There can be few approaches that you can look up to before performing any `db` task.

1. If the list size which you are inserting is more than the data stored in the `db`, then you should check which data is already available and skip that from inserting.
2. If the list size is smaller then you can use `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE` while inserting.